# Need help: Building Java Web-Service(s) and .NET/WPF Client consuming it

Tags: java, .net, wpf, wcf, web-services

I am required to build couple of Java WebServices on JBoss 5.x. One of the services will be consumed by a WPF Application. I am quite new to the world of WebServices and researching more on that. Needed to know if someone has been through the same and can share the pointers on how to achieve it.

I am reading one of the articles on JBoss Communities: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r2/html/ch12.html

I am not sure if web services explained here are interoperable with my WPF Client. I am planning to use WCF to consume these web services.

Can anyone share some pointers about it?

Thanks!

Comment: The article you linked is ancient - JBoss 4 and Java 1.4. Use a newer resource.

Comment: Yeah. Figured that out. Will look at the latest one

Answer (score 0):

WCF can consume [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) web services as well as [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) ones. I recommend looking into [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-RS) for REST, and/or [JAX-WS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-WS) for SOAP. Both JAX-RS and JAX-WS are APIs that let you create web services by annotating Java code, rather than having to work with XML configuration files.

These days, SOAP is often considered over-engineered, and REST is considered leaner. There are [a ton of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=soap%20vs%20rest) comparing the two on SO.

Comment: I see. Let me try it out and will update the post about how it goes